# how to make a column add based on a previous value a group of figures in another column sequentially on timeline

Tags: sql-server

What I am looking to do is create a column that looks at the Result value, adds them to the previous result and based on a group by DayStartDate.
I have a timeline including hour of day that creates individual events.
Basically so I can create a chronological view to show the total amount of the material moved at a specific point of the day.
I am trying to see if I can do this in SQL rather than Power BI to reduce the load on the Power BI.

[image: current filtered out result]

I have been trying to create a new column that will sum each event based on the result in the other column. I have shown what I am trying to get in the new column and what I currently have.

[image: desired result]

This is my current query.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```sql
SELECT
    c.*,
    YEAR(c.DayStartDate) * 10000 + MONTH(c.DayStartDate) * 100 + DAY(c.DayStartDate) AS DateID,
    DATEPART(hh, c.EndDate) * 10000 + DATEPART(mi, c.EndDate) * 100 + DATEPART(ss, c.EndDate) AS TimeId,
    42.5 AS Payload,
    CASE
      WHEN c.VehicleId != LAG(c.VehicleId) 
             OVER (ORDER BY c.VehicleId, c.EndDate)
         THEN CAST('00:00:00' AS time)
       WHEN c.DayStartDate != LAG(c.DayStartDate) OVER (ORDER BY c.VehicleId, c.EndDate)
         THEN CAST('00:00:00' AS time)
       WHEN LAG(c.DayStartDate) OVER (ORDER BY c.VehicleId, c.EndDate) IS NULL
         THEN CAST('00:00:00' AS time)
       WHEN c.ShiftNumber != LAG(c.ShiftNumber) OVER (ORDER BY c.VehicleId, c.EndDate)
         THEN CAST('00:00:00' AS time)
       ELSE
         CAST(CONVERT(varchar(22), c.EndDate - LAG(c.EndDate) OVER (ORDER BY c.VehicleId, c.EndDate), 114) AS time) 
       END AS Duration
FROM   (
    SELECT
        b.*,
        CASE
          WHEN CAST(b.EndDate AS time) BETWEEN '00:00:00.000' AND '07:14:59.900'
            THEN CAST(CONVERT(date, b.EndDate - 1) AS date)
          ELSE
            CAST(CAST(b.EndDate AS date) AS date)
          END AS DayStartDate,
        CASE WHEN (CAST(b.EndDate AS time) BETWEEN 
                           '00:00:00.000' AND '07:14:59.900') OR
                           (CAST(b.EndDate AS time) BETWEEN '19:14:59.900' AND '23:59:59.900')
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ShiftNumber
     FROM    (
         SELECT
            e.EventId,
            ed.Name AS EventName,
            va.VehicleId,
            da.DriverId,
            dateadd(HH, DATEPART(TZ, e.EndDate AT time Zone si.TimeZoneInfoId) / 60, e.EndDate) AS EndDate,
            e.GPSLatEnd,
            e.GPSLongEnd
          FROM    Events e INNER JOIN
                  EventDefs ed ON ed.EventDefId = e.EventDefId INNER JOIN
                  Segments s ON s.SegmentId = e.SegmentId INNER JOIN
                  DriversAll da ON da.DriverId = s.DriverId INNER JOIN
                  Trips t ON t .TripId = s.TripId INNER JOIN
                  VehiclesAll va ON va.VehicleId = t .VehicleId INNER JOIN
                  Sites si ON si.SiteId = va.SiteId 
          WHERE  e.EventDefId = 1381
      ) b
) c
```

Comment: Very difficult to tell you anything as it's unclear what you are trying to do. Few comments: **1.** You need to learn to format your code better, I'm not sure how even you can understand what's going on **2.** Learn the benefit of `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (...` to apply calculated fields within a query. This allows you to write the calculation once and refer to it anywhere within that subquery level, and probably means you need to subquery less **3.** You need to describe the exact logic you are trying to implement, it's not clear at the moment, we can only guess based on your existing query

Comment: `ShiftNumber` can be simplified to say `endTimeOfDay NOT BETWEEN '07:15:00' AND '19:15:00'`. You have a `CONVERT(varchar(22)...` which should be `CONVERT(time,`. Be aware also that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, and often it's better to use half-open intervals `mydate >= start and mydate < end`

Comment: Thanks Charlie. Basically what I am trying to do is create a query that rather than return the result Payload as the individual payload on that event I want to return a result of the payload + the previous value. It does this for the same DayStartDate then for the next day starts again. So it will give me a running tally on the specific date based on each event. Basically trying to see if I can get SQl to do the result rather than transforming the data in other software to view it.

Comment: Yes of course you can get SQL to do something like that. I still don't get how what you just said has anything to do with the query you supplied, why are you stripping out times and dates separately, seems to be some kind of shift times maybe? etc. Please [edit] your question to explain the logic fully, and please supply proper sample data as *code* (`create` and `insert` statements).

Comment: did you post the correct query ? Looks like it is totally not related to your question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data and the required result and also *ignoring the query that you posted*, it looks like you want a running total of `Result` by day

you can use `SUM() OVER ()`

```
Tally = SUM (Result) OVER (PARTITION BY DayStartD ORDER BY EndDate)
```

If this is not what you wanted, please update your question accordingly